# Attempting to migrate the .net core projects from 2.2 to 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, .net-core

Trying to migrate the projects from .net core 2.2 to 3.1. In local debug the whole application works correctly. I've tried to publish my application on IIS. After publishing I go to the site url and see the error:

> Error 500.31 - ANCM Failed to Find Native Dependencies in IIS
>
> Common solutions to this issue:
>    The specified version of Microsoft.NetCore.App or Microsoft.AspNetCore.App was not found.
>
> Specific error detected by ANCM:
>    A fatal error was encountered. The library 'hostpolicy.dll' required to execute the application was not found in

`dotnet --info` command result:

[image: dotnet --info]

All projects has the target framework `.netcoreapp 3.1`, libraries are `.netstandart 2.0`.
I've tried re-installing SDK, Visual Studio 2019. I've updated every nuget packages from 2.2 to 3.1.1, that are connected with Microsoft.

Hosting bundle 3.1.1 is also installed. Any ideas how to solve this problem?

**UPD.** The publish command:

```
dotnet publish $projectPath -m --no-build -c:$publishConfiguration -o $destinationPath -v q -r $targetPlatform /p:EnvironmentName=$publishEnvironment --self-contained false;
```

target-platform = `win-x64`. The hosting model is `InProgress`.

**UPD 2.** The result of `dotnet list package` on solution: https://gist.github.com/AndreiKhotko/60aafeb42566ac3e3fadfab2d0209dde

**UPD 3.** The `ASP.NET Core Diagnostics` generated report: https://gist.github.com/AndreiKhotko/2a193b4121c4399e0a00bfef708140da

**UPD 4.** Sorry, I haven't specified the whole error message. There is the last part of it (see above for the first part of it):

> Failed to run as a self-contained app. If this should be a
>   framework-dependent app, specify the appropriate framework in '*.runtime.config'.

The content of `*.runtime.config`:

```
{
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "tfm": "netcoreapp3.1",
    "includedFrameworks": [
      {
        "name": "Microsoft.NETCore.App",
        "version": "3.1.1"
      },
      {
        "name": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.App",
        "version": "3.1.1"
      }
    ],
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you do a `dotnet list package` in the solution directory and create a gist of the results?

Comment: @MartinFrøhlich sure. I will notice you after updating the question

Comment: @MartinFrøhlich check it out. Now I see that there are the packages .net Tests with version `16.0`. Seems like these references breaks the publishing. I will check it later

Comment: Information like your application pool settings are not shared above. https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html You might run the diagnostics and edit your question to include the report.

Comment: make sure you assigned the iis user permission to the published folder.try to change the web.config handler from AspNetCoreModuleV2 to AspNetCoreModule. also check the event viewer for more detail.

Comment: @LexLi I've added a report. Please, check it

Comment: @JalpaPanchal change module to `AspNetCoreModule` is not good idea. Event viewer shows the same errors. Their descriptions are useless

Comment: Please remove `--self-contained false` from the publish command. Why do you want to disable that while choosing win-x64? That only leaves the generated binaries in inconsistency.

Comment: @LexLi yeah, it fixes my problem. Thank you! But why `--self-contained false` option broke my app? And what if I want to publish the app on `linux-x64`? Do I need to use `--self-contained false` in this scenario?

Comment: @LexLi why my app is tried to run self-contained when my app is framework dependent?

Answer (score 3):

The cause is that `dotnet publish` has very ambiguous behaviors when a combination of switches are served.

In your case, `--self-contained false` and `-r linux-x64` are kind of conflicting to each other. `-r linux-x64` forces to generate self-contained binaries, while `--self-contained false` seems to remove important runtime dependencies from the final files. It is too bad that the dotnet CLI does not give you a warning/error for that.

If your goal is to use framework dependent deployment, follow the instructions strictly, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/deploy-with-cli#framework-dependent-deployment and remove `-r linux-x64` from your command.

Comment: I think you should add a link to `dotnet publish` command, especially for `-r` option. As said in that post, `-r|--runtime <RUNTIME_IDENTIFIER>` Publishes the application for a given runtime. _This is used when_ creating **a self-contained deployment** (SCD). For a list of Runtime Identifiers (RIDs), see the RID catalog. Default is to publish a framework-dependent deployment (FDD).

Comment: My goal is to achieve a FDE (framework dependent executable). And I really need -r identifier. But native dependencies conflicts broke the app